# MAMP vhosts stopped working after a restart

Tags: apache, mamp, vhosts

I have been using MAMP for a long time now, and everything has been fairly peachy until this week. I have looked through SO and google (inside and out), but I cannot for the life of me figure out why all of a sudden I cannot access my sites after I restarted my computer for an update...

Nothing has changed, I still have the proper names in my hosts and httpd-vhosts.conf files.
Has anyone had their vhosts with MAMP suddenly just stop working all together? This is driving me MAD!

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hoh/public/"
ServerName hoh.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and the hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   hoh.local learning.dev mvc.dev
```

The site I was literally working on earlier today is the hoh.local one (it was hoh.dev but that wasn't working either so I changed it in hopes it would magically work again).

Apache Log:

```
[Fri Oct 17 17:23:46 2014] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 6730)
[Fri Oct 17 17:23:46 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Oct 17 17:23:46 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Oct 17 17:23:46 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.6.1 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 17 17:29:40 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Oct 17 17:30:08 2014] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 380)
[Fri Oct 17 17:30:08 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Oct 17 17:30:08 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Oct 17 17:30:08 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.6.1 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 17 17:30:13 2014] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/docs-assets
[Fri Oct 17 18:01:47 2014] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/docs-assets
[Fri Oct 17 18:09:13 2014] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English
[Fri Oct 17 18:09:13 2014] [notice] cannot use a full URL in a 401 ErrorDocument directive --- ignoring!
[Fri Oct 17 18:12:16 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Oct 17 18:12:18 2014] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 1278)
[Fri Oct 17 18:12:18 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Oct 17 18:12:18 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Oct 17 18:12:18 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.5.17 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 17 18:12:21 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Oct 17 18:13:13 2014] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 1426)
[Fri Oct 17 18:13:13 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Oct 17 18:13:13 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Oct 17 18:13:13 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.5.17 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 17 18:15:45 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Oct 17 18:16:37 2014] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 1693)
[Fri Oct 17 18:16:37 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Oct 17 18:16:37 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Oct 17 18:16:37 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.5.17 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Q: What do the logs say???

Comment: Not really a server guy, so didn't even think of that, but I've attached the apache logs :)

Comment: `[client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English` You are accessing it via ipv6 protocol and by server configuration were denied access to it. Are you really trying to access it by `hoh.local` because I do not see that in the referer string - `localhost` was used.

Comment: And also it shows port `8888`, not `80`. Check by nestat which ports apache is listening. Something like this in console `netstat -p tcp`

Comment: thanks for the comments! I removed the *:80 so now it's just * since I need 8888 for my phpmyadmin to work. But, still no go. Also, these are the localhost results from the netstat: 
tcp4       0      0  localhost.26164        localhost.49725        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.49725        localhost.26164        ESTABLISHED

Comment: and yes I'm accessing it as hoh.local - so not sure why it's not displaying :/

Comment: Ended up just setting it all up using the apache and php etc that Mac comes with instead...less headaches than dealing with MAMP lately, lol!

Comment: I had symptoms very similar to yours. The .DS_Store file is a Mac-only, Finder metadata file, its not part of the Wordpress site. So I simply deleted it. That fixed the "client denied by server configuration" error. The bad news is my own site still doesn't come up, and there are no errors left in the logs to explain why. :-( Still, I thought it was worth mentioning that the .DS_Store error is probably a red herring.